# Ahoy_email gem : clicked_at, opened_at not getting updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ahoy

I'm using [ahoy_email](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email) ruby gem to track the emails I send. It should give me the time at when it is opened and clicked. But it's not working properly to give the time. What I'm missing.

Note: I run the project in my localhost

Comment: did you add `track click: true` and `track open: true`

Comment: @RajarshiDas yes I added. That didn't help

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Make sure your server is accessible from the outside world so the image can be fetched.

A little background: I eventually figured that it worked from the godaddy webclient but not gmail, and thats because the webclient was just loading the image from my browser (so it could see my 'localhost'), but I believe gmail uses a proxy server to load images (https://filippo.io/how-the-new-gmail-image-proxy-works-and-what-does-this-mean-for-you/) so it couldn't find it.

I've been using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) lately to make my localhost outside accessible (temporarily!) and been liking it.

Comment: I am phasing issue on click event. i am not updating clicked_at.
This is my mail send result.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    

  
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  
  
    <h1>Welcome to example.com</h1>
    <a data-disable-tracking="true" href="..."></a>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  <img src="http://localhost:3000/ahoy/messages/vAkGgY2nRMQTK5NbxvJAtzCOxjFoSVKN/open.gif" width="1" height="1">

  <img src="http://localhost:3000/ahoy/messages/vAkGgY2nRMQTK5NbxvJAtzCOxjFoSVKN/open.gif" width="1" height="1">
</body>
</html>